# Reading a text file using BufferedReader.readLine() is too slow

Tags: java, php, io

I am trying to read a text file which contains about 1000 very long lines. Entire file stands at about 1.4MB. 
I am using BufferedReader's readLine method to read file. What happens is it takes 8-10 seconds to print the output on console. I tried the same using fgets of php and it prints all the same lines in blink of an eye!!! How is it possible?
Below is the code I am using

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ClickLogDataImporter {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
            new ClickLogDataImporter().getFileData();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClickLogDataImporter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void getFileData() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String path = "/home/shantanu/Documents";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(path+"/sample.txt")));
        String line = "";
        while((line = (br.readLine())) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    }
}
```

PHP code

```
<?php
    $fileName = "/home/shantanu/Documents/sample.txt";
    $file = fopen($fileName, 'r');
    while(($line = fgets($file)) != false) {
        echo $line."\n";
    }
?>
```

Please enlighten me about this issue

Comment: please check the edited code. As rightly explained by DJon, I was doing two incomparable processes. Reading line by line and dumping entire content are two different things. So I performed another test, now by using fgets. And result is still the same

Comment: I assue, both programs are run in the same way, also from command line?

Comment: yes both on command line

Comment: OK, so, in which moment you start to measure time? I don't see that in code. So the problem could be in JRE loading time, not the execution time of your code.

Comment: ok, when I commented out console output. java takes about 80-90ms, and  php is taking not more than 5 ms! I double checked it. But it is so

Comment: So it's probably how much it takes to load classes behind System.out.println. You should do initial System.out.prinlnt(), and than start your timer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think PHP just prints the file given the method you used, Java reads the file and gets every lines from it, that means checking every character for a line breaker, the process does not seem to be the same at all.

```
string file_get_contents
```

If you try and print each line one by one from the file with PHP, it should be slower.

Comment: Please check the edited code. Now I used fgets in php. So read all lines one by one. Result didn't vary

Comment: Are you using PHP from a browser or a shell? Then it must be your console output, remove `System.out.printl(line)` and see how long it takes.

Comment: i am running both from shell.

Comment: If you can provide the sample file, or give us the size and number of lines, I can test both methods and tell you if I have the same results.

Comment: there are 1000 lines and every line is at least 1000 character long

Comment: I made a file with 1000 lines of 1000 zeros, file is 978 KB, it took 0 ms to load and 1404 ms to print on Netbeans' console.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30837/discussion-between-djon-and-shades88)

Answer (score 0):

8 seconds for that code sounds *much* too long to me. I suspect something else is going on, to be honest. Are you sure it's not console output which is taking a long time?

I suggest you time it (e.g. with [`System.nanoTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)) writing out the total time at the end, but run it with a console minimized. I suspect you'll find it's fast enough then.

Comment: both codes are printing lines on console. Still php is beating!

Comment: @Shades88: Maybe PHP has faster console access for some reason. I very much doubt that the time is taken *reading* the file. It's easy to test this. If you get rid of the console output in Java - just count the lines you read and write out that count at the end for example - how long does it take?

Comment: I conducted the same test. commenting console output, java takes 80-90ms however, php takes only 3-5ms!!

Comment: @Shades88: My guess is at that point it depends on OS caching... and JIT compilation. You may well find that if you run the method several times, it's very fast. Is this program actually representative of anything you're trying to do though, or were you just trying to compare the speed of PHP and Java? If so, it's not a terribly useful comparison IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that just the console output that is slow? Now that you know that you're file is read correctly, try by commenting out the line `System.out.println(line);`.

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents loads all the file contents into a String, with your code in Java you are reading and printing line by line.
If you are testing inside an IDE like Eclipse, the console output can be quite slow.
If you want the exact behavior of file_get_contents, you can use this dirty code :

```
 File f = new File(path, "sample.txt");
 ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(new Long(Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, f.length())).intValue());
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
 byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 8];
 int size;
 while((size = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
    bos.write(buf, 0, size);
 }
 fis.close();
 bos.close();
 System.out.println(new String(bos.toByteArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you r using readline it will go and read the file 1000 times for each line . Try using  the read function with a very big buffer say over 28000 or so. It will then read a file say a total of 60 times for 1.4 MB which is much lesser than 1000. If u use a small buffer of 1000, then its gonna read the file around 1300 or something which is even slower than 1000( readline ). Also while printing the lines use print instead of println since the lines are not exactly  lines but an array of characters.

Answer (score -1):

Readers are usually slow, you should try Stream readers which are fast. And make sure that FIlE opening process is not taking time. If File is opened and stream objects are created and then measure time, then you can figure out exactly it is due to File opening issue or reading the file issue. Make sure that system io load is not high at the time of this operation, otherwise you measurement will go bad.

```
 BufferedInputStream reader=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/shantanu/Documents/sample.txt"));
 byte[] line=new byte[1024];
 while(reader.read(line)>0) {
 System.out.println(new String(line));
 }
```

Comment: This is still doing the same work - converting binary data into text data - just at a different point. Additionally, suggesting using `InputStream` for text data is fundamentally a bad idea. For example, your code could end up reading *part* of a character (e.g. the first byte of a two-byte character using UTF-8) and you'd never know. What's more, your code doesn't use the return value of `read`, so you're creating a string using the whole buffer whether or not it's full of useful data.